# sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document works slowly?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am using MS SQL Server tabled-valued-function `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document` to calclulate keyword occurrence for all indexed items, but it works extremely slow. 
Is there a faster way to calculate word occurence?